# Azure Logic Apps - is it possible to have a metric that shows, per resource, the SUM of all Trigger Fired?

Tags: azure, metrics, azure-logic-apps

I have a very simple use case: I have an Azure Subscription used internally for testing and demo purposes. A lot of members of the team are regularly creating Logic Apps for tests and demo.
I want to be sure that we don't have a lot of Triggers Fired (i.e. each second...) in order to avoid too much consumption.

When I go to Metrics in order to display the sum of "Trigger Fired", I need to first select a Logic App and I can't select multiple Logic Apps at a time. How can I proceed if I want to see all Trigger Fired metrics for all Logic Apps?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you just want to get the metrics at the same time like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Pj9.png) or you want to get the value in one metric?

Comment: Looking at getting the value in one metric, so it will be easy then to determine the price of all these Logic Apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want it show multiple logic app fired values in one metric, you could set a metric show one logic app trigger fired value then click **Add metric**, it will prompt it to configure the details. After these, you will see the value in one metric.

[image]

**Update**: hope this is what you want. You need go to Logs, query the logs you want. And how to set the monitor to get the logs, you could refer to this doc:[logic apps monitor your logic apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-monitor-your-logic-apps-oms). Then query in the `Logs`.

The below is my test.

```
 AzureDiagnostics 
| where Category == "WorkflowRuntime" 
| where OperationName == "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/workflowTriggerStarted" 
| summarize ccc=count(Category) by bin_at(TimeGenerated, 1h, now()), ResourceGroup ,ResourceProvider
```

The select the CHART.
[image]

And from the doc you could find **Logic Apps Management** to view logs, it also provide a way to view runs like the below picture.

[image]

**Note**: with this way it only show you the logs after you set the `Log Analytics`, the before logs it won't be stored.

Comment: Ok, and do you think that it is possible to have one metric that represents the sum of all other metrics? Because I have around 200 logic apps...

Comment: So you want to calculate the sum of all trigger fired?

Comment: @David GROSPELIER, I have update the answer. Hope this is what you want. If you still have other problem, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Ok but what I'm looking for is a way to say "ok, this Azure solution composed by all these Logic Apps and generating x Billable Actions, meaning that it costs x€/month based on the current load". You see?

Comment: For the logic app pricing details, you could refer to this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-pricing. Mostly, the pricing is metered by the actions, connectors, ISE and Integration account.